# displaying labels horizontally instead of vertically in thymeleaf

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I want to be able to display a series of skill tags in a horizontal order such as 
JSP XML Java C#  etc.

**Update:** 
Ok,I did try what the commenter suggested.  It seems to be another issue.

Here are two examples of the issue with and without a thymeleaf directive.

Ok, So if I explicitly add the items in html, it behaves as I want
[image]

This gives this result.  This is what I want.

[image]

But if I do it as a th:each, then each item is on a separate line
[image]

And this gives the following:

[image]

What should I change?

**ANSWER:**
OK, found the issue.  You need to put the th:each on the right element.

[image]

Note that it is on the li and not the ui.  That makes it work.

Comment: The CSS styles associated with the list-skills. That has nothing to do with spring or thymeleaf.

Comment: I made an update to the original question.  If I put n <li> items in the <ul> then they are all printed in the same line as I want.  With the thymeleaf each they explicitly go to a second line

Comment: found the answer and placed it in the question

Comment: @EvilJinious1 You can post the answer and accept it after two days of posting. Please don't post solutions in your question. ;)

Comment: Because it was marked as a duplicate, it won't let me actually answer it.